# Docker common network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Is there any way to make a docker container that is accessing to all docker networks at the same time ? The idea is that I have 2 docker networks.

Let's say that they are called demo1 and demo2.
I have another docker container (called Front) that should reach demo1 and demo2 at the same time.

I can do that by declaring external networks in my docker-compose file.
However, I want to be able to declare demo3 and attach the Front container to it "dynamically", without modifying the compose file of the container and if it's possible, without restarting it.

So, I am trying to find an architecture that makes my container Front connect to any added docker network dynamically.

I can create a script in a crontab, but the idea is to do it properly.
The need is to get a common container, which can reach any other container.

In a docker compose syntaxe, I image something like this:

`networks:
  all:
      name: '*'
      external: true`

Is it possible ? How ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is [Connect a running container to a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#connect-a-running-container-to-a-network):

**Examples**

***Connect a running container to a network***

```
$ docker network connect multi-host-network container1
```

Just find the new network name and connect your `Front container` to this network out of composefile.

Comment: This is not really my use case. I want it to connect any new docker network is awailable. I add a line to my question to be more precise. thx

Comment: All options are [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference) which I guess you have already have a look at. Another way maybe set a network for this common container, and force all new service also use this network. If this also not your aim, I have no idea. You can wait for other folks, good luck!